# javascript array assign to multiple variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got a bit logic problem. I want to assign array to several variables. But it doesn't work. Appreciate your help.

### PS: variable `values` will be dynamic.

```
function Case(values){
  var A = [];
  var B = [];
  var C = [];
  if (temp === 0){
    A.push(values);
    temp+=1;
  } else if (temp === 1){
    B.push(values);
    temp+=1;
  } else if (temp === 2){
    C.push(values);
    temp = 0;
  }

  return [A,B,C];   
}

var temp = 0;
var values = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7 , 8];

Case(values);
```

### if var values = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7 , 8];Output expected:

```
A = [5, 6];
B = [4, 7];
A = [3, 8];
```

### if var values = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7 , 8, 10, 20, 30];Output expected:

```
A = [5, 6, 10];
B = [4, 7, 20];
A = [3, 8, 30];
```

Comment: already devine `i`. but still not got output expected

Comment: Your `i` is an array, not a number.

Comment: i expect, output is : `A = [5, 6];
B = [4, 7];
A = [3, 8]; `

Comment: Why would you expect that output?  You pushed the entire `values` array into A, B and C.  You never split out some values into each so why would you ever think that some values are in A, some different values are in B and so on.  Then, `return A, B, C` makes no sense either.  Not even sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: hi thanks. already add some loop but still didn't get output i expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Case(values){
  console.log("values: " + values);
  var A = [];
  var B = [];
  var C = [];
  var i = 0;
  while(i < values.length) { 
    A.push(values[i++]);
    B.push(values[i++]);
    C.push(values[i++]);
  }
 
  console.log("A: " + A);
  console.log("B: " + B);
  console.log("C: " + C);
}

var values = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7 , 8];
Case(values);
values = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7 , 8, 10, 20, 30];
Case(values);
```

NOTE: `values` array should always have the number of elements in multiple of 3 because there are 3 arrays in this case A,B and C.

Comment: To improve the answer, `return [A, B, C];`

Comment: @user3284463 logic is there, it can be modified as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is length fixed, you just have to do:

```
function Case(values){
  var A = [];
  var B = [];
  var C = [];
  var res;
  var temp = 0;    

  A.push(values[0]);
  A.push(values[3]);
  B.push(values[1]);
  B.push(values[4]);
  C.push(values[2]); 
  C.push(values[5]);
  return [A,B,C]
}
```

Comment: hi thanks. edited my question. array length isn't fixed. the variable `values` will be dynamic. so i need dynamic method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Case(values){
  var i = values;
  var A = [];
  var B = [];
  var C = [];
  var temp = 0;    

  A = A.concat(getItem(0));
  B = B.concat(getItem(1));
  C = C.concat(getItem(2));
  
  console.log(A); console.log(B); console.log(C);
}

function getItem(j){
 return values.filter(function(v,k){
   if((k == j) ||(k == (j+3))){
    return true;
 }
  });
}


var values = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7 , 8];
Case(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach would be to split the array into chunks of 3, and then transpose the chunks.

```js
function chunksOf(arr, n) {
  var i = 0, result = [];
  while (i < arr.length) {
    result.push(arr.slice(i, i += n));
  }
  return result;
}

function transpose(arr) {
  return arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.map(a => a[i]));
}

var values = [5, 4, 3, 6, 7 , 8];
var [a, b, c] = transpose(chunksOf(values, 3));

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```